# MySQL Retrieving last record from table1 and join data from table 2

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have two table (below codes) , want to retrieve **last** row of `trackers_data` table and `GROUP BY tracker_id` and *(join)* information of each `tracker_id` from Table `Devices`

**Devices/Table:**

```
        /*Table: devices*/
id  tracker_id  name        device_name
-----------------------------------
1   1242        Driver A    Benz
2   1255        Driver B    Volvo
3   1256        Driver C    BMW
```

**Trackers_data/Table:**

```
     /*Table: trackers_data*/
id  tracker_id  longitude   latitude
-------------------------------------
5       1255    53.25       11.52
6       1255    52.63       11.63
7       1242    52.23       13.11
8       1242    52.25       15.27
9       1242    54.63       13.86
```

**Example/Results should like below :**

```
     /* Results */
id  tracker_id  lonitude    latitude    name        device_name
6   1255        52.63       11.63       Driver B    Volvo
9   1242        54.63       13.86       Driver C    BMW
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this solution:

```
SELECT b.*, c.name, c.device_name
FROM   (SELECT MAX(id) AS id FROM trackers_data GROUP BY tracker_id) a
JOIN   trackers_data b ON a.id = b.id
JOIN   devices c ON b.tracker_id = c.tracker_id
```